# Can not start ContainerD container on Windows

Tags: windows, containerd

I've been following [Gentle ContainerD on Windows Guide For You](https://blog.devgenius.io/gentle-containerd-on-windows-guide-for-you-50d4a46daccf) to setup ContainerD on my Windows 10 machine but somehow I can not start any example from this tutorial.

Command is:   `crictl.exe runp --runtime runhcs-wcow-process .\pod-config.yaml`
Error is:

```
crictl.exe runp --runtime runhcs-wcow-process .\pod-config.yaml
time="2022-03-18T19:39:38+02:00" level=fatal msg="run pod sandbox: 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox \"7db0b08199861ffc0a68b869990c2ce1e2cee29df2579f9502ec584fbd5d2913\": plugin type=\"nat\" name=\"natContainerD\" failed (add): 
error creating endpoint hcnCreateEndpoint failed in Win32: IP address is either invalid or not part of any configured subnet(s). (0x803b001e) {\"Success\":false,\"Error\":\"IP address is either invalid or not part of any configured subnet(s). \",\"ErrorCode\":2151350302} : 
endpoint config &{ 7db0b08199861ffc0a68b869990c2ce1e2cee29df2579f9502ec584fbd5d2913_natContainerD 6160b2e0-4525-4bbc-b725-135c55fc741b  [] [{ 0}] { [] [] []} [{172.22.208.1 0.0.0.0/0 0}]  0 {2 0}}"
```

I guess I didn't configured my `cni` network right (?)

Here are steps what I did to setup network:

```
$subnet='10.0.0.0/16'
$gateway='10.0.0.1'
New-HnsNetwork -Type NAT -AddressPrefix $subnet -Gateway $gateway -Name "natContainerD"
```

Please note that I can not create network with name `nat` because it was already exist (from Docker ?) os I named this one as `natContainerD`

Then I configure the `cni` itself (as in tutorial above):

```
@"
{
    "cniVersion": "0.2.0",
    "name": "nat",
    "type": "nat",
    "master": "Internet",
    "ipam": {
        "subnet": "$subnet",
        "routes": [
            {
                "gateway": "$gateway"
            }
        ]
    },
    "capabilities": {
        "portMappings": true,
        "dns": true
    }
}
"@ | Set-Content "$env:ProgramFiles\containerd\cni\conf\0-containerd-nat.conf" -Force
```

However, no matter what settings I change in this file, I am still unable to start any containers :(

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi Alex, did you end up get the containers running on `Windows 10` as you originally wanted or did you have to switch to `Windows Server 2019 (LTSC)` or `Windows Server 2022 (LTSC)`.

Comment: @FrankLiu I have to switch to Windows that support ContainerD

Comment: Which Windows edition did you end up using that supports ContainerD?

Comment: If you need an engine only for Windows containers, [this](https://github.com/slonopotamus/stevedore) was an easier alternative for me. Just run `winget install stevedore` and restart. Then use `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022` as you would with Docker Desktop installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps I tried to install containerd on Windows Server 2022.

1. Install Windows Features

   ```
   Add-WindowsFeature Containers,Hyper-V,Hyper-V-Tools,Hyper-V-PowerShell -Restart -IncludeManagementTools
   ```
2. Install [containerd 1.6.1](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/)

   ```
   # Download containerd 1.6.1
   curl.exe -LO https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.6.1/containerd-1.6.1-windows-amd64.tar.gz

   tar xvf containerd-1.6.1-windows-amd64.tar.gz
   mkdir -force "C:\Program Files\containerd"
   mv ./bin/* "C:\Program Files\containerd"
   Remove-Item bin

   . "C:\Program Files\containerd\containerd.exe" config default | Out-File "C:\Program Files\containerd\config.toml" -Encoding ascii

   Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess "$Env:ProgramFiles\containerd\containerd.exe"

   . "$Env:ProgramFiles\containerd\containerd.exe" --register-service

   Start-Service containerd

   $env:PATH = "C:\Program Files\containerd;" + $env:PATH
   ```
3. Configure container networking

   ```
   mkdir -force "C:\Program Files\containerd\cni\bin"
   mkdir -force "C:\Program Files\containerd\cni\conf"
   ```

   Download `windows-container-networking-cni-amd64-v0.2.0.zip` file from [microsoft/windows-container-networking](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-networking)

   ```
   curl.exe -LO https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-networking/releases/download/v0.2.0/windows-container-networking-cni-amd64-v0.2.0.zip
   Expand-Archive windows-container-networking-cni-amd64-v0.2.0.zip -DestinationPath "C:\Program Files\containerd\cni\bin" -Force
   Remove-Item windows-container-networking-cni-amd64-v0.2.0.zip
   ```

   > You have to download the source code from [microsoft/windows-container-networking](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-networking) repo and build your own `nat.exe` from the source. It because the binary version in the Releases are outdated. It will not working in WS2022. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-networking/issues/65).

   Creating a `nat` network

   ```
   curl.exe -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/SDN/master/Kubernetes/windows/hns.psm1
   Import-Module ./hns.psm1

   $subnet="10.0.0.0/16"
   $gateway="10.0.0.1"
   New-HNSNetwork -Type NAT -AddressPrefix $subnet -Gateway $gateway -Name "nat"

   @"
   {
       "cniVersion": "0.2.0",
       "name": "nat",
       "type": "nat",
       "master": "Ethernet",
       "ipam": {
           "subnet": "$subnet",
           "routes": [
               {
                   "gateway": "$gateway"
               }
           ]
       },
       "capabilities": {
           "portMappings": true,
           "dns": true
       }
   }
   "@ | Set-Content "C:\Program Files\containerd\cni\conf\0-containerd-nat.conf" -Force
   ```

### Running a container using `ctr`

1. Check Windows version

   ```
   cmd /c ver
   ```

   ```
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.20348.587]
   ```
2. Pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022` and `hello-world` images

   ```
   ctr.exe image pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
   ctr.exe image pull registry.hub.docker.com/library/hello-world:nanoserver-ltsc2022
   ```
3. Run containers

   ```
   ctr.exe run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022 hello cmd /c echo Hello World
   ctr container rm hello
   ```

   ```
   ctr.exe run --rm registry.hub.docker.com/library/hello-world:nanoserver-ltsc2022 hello-world
   ```

   ```
   ctr run --cni --rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022 test curl.exe -s https://ifconfig.co/
   ```

### Running a Pod and Container using `crictl`

1. Install `crictl` tool

   ```
   curl.exe -LO https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/v1.23.0/crictl-v1.23.0-windows-amd64.tar.gz
   tar xvf crictl-v1.23.0-windows-amd64.tar.gz
   mv crictl.exe "C:\Program Files\containerd"
   ```
2. Configure `crictl` config

   ```
   mkdir -Force "$home\.crictl"

   @"
   runtime-endpoint: npipe://./pipe/containerd-containerd
   image-endpoint: npipe://./pipe/containerd-containerd
   timeout: 10
   #debug: true
   "@ | Set-Content "$home\.crictl\crictl.yaml" -Force

   crictl.exe info
   ```
3. Pull [Pause container image](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/#pause-container) (`k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6`)

   ```
   crictl pull k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6
   ```
4. Creating a sandbox / Pod

   ```
   @"
   {
       "metadata": {
           "name": "hello-world-sandbox",
           "namespace": "default",
           "attempt": 1,
           "uid": "hdishd83djaidwnduwk28bcsb"
       },
       "log_directory": "/tmp"
   }
   "@ | Set-Content "pod-config.json" -Force

   mkdir C:\tmp

   $POD_ID=(crictl runp .\pod-config.json)
   ```
5. Creating a container

   ```
   @"
   {
     "metadata": {
         "name": "hello-world:nanoserver-ltsc2022"
     },
     "image":{
         "image": "hello-world:nanoserver-ltsc2022"
     },
     "log_path":"hello-world.0.log"
   }
   "@ | Set-Content "container-config.json" -Force

   $CONTAINER_ID=(crictl create $POD_ID .\container-config.json .\pod-config.json)
   ```
6. Start container

   ```
   crictl start $CONTAINER_ID
   ```
7. Check logs in that container

   ```
   crictl logs $CONTAINER_ID
   ```

   ```
   Hello from Docker!
   This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

   To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
    1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
    2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
       (windows-amd64, nanoserver-ltsc2022)
    3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
       executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
    4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
       to your terminal.

   To try something more ambitious, you can run a Windows Server container with:
    PS C:\> docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 powershell

   Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
    https://hub.docker.com/

   For more examples and ideas, visit:
    https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
   ```
8. Checking Pods and Containers

   ```
   crictl pods
   crictl ps -a
   ```
9. Delete Container and Pod

   ```
   crictl rm $CONTAINER_ID
   crictl stopp $POD_ID
   crictl rmp $POD_ID
   ```

Comment: Yes - there's a difference in downloaded version of `nat.exe` from `microsoft/windows-container-networking` and compiled one (about 5 Mg difference) but container could not be started with `ctr.exe`. Error is: `ctr: no match for platform in manifest sha256:fbb9fae2b9d6477ba105f2faa805db850c90292c84b080d63acbf21cc95b4b39: not found`

Comment: @AlexF I think you have to use Windows Server 2019 (LTSC) or Windows Server 2022 (LTSC) to try this. Windows 10 21H1 is not supported.

Comment: Is there any option to run those commands (`ctr.exe` and `crictl`) as a regular user ?. It works only if I start them as administrator :(

Comment: for me windows-server 2019 most power-shell commands are not working, although i use 64bit version of powershell with admin-rights. Additionally while setting up HNS Network the vmcompute.dll could not be found.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt make sure that you run the very first paragraph: `Add-WindowsFeature Containers,Hyper-V,Hyper-V-Tools,Hyper-V-PowerShell -Restart -IncludeManagementTools`. It seems that you missing HyperV tools

Comment: Add-Windows Commandset is not recognized, nor 64bit powershell nor 32bit... I enabled container with Server-manager tool, hyper-V too.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt It's `Add-WindowsFeature`, but `Add-Windows`.

Comment: I did no mistake there, its not recognized.